# Can I implement a heap using only percolateDown?

Tags: c, data-structures, heap

I need to implement a Heap data structure in C. 
While I was doing some research, I see people using buildHeap(), constructHeap() to convert an array into a heap. My question is, instead of implementing those functions, can I just call percolateDown() on the newly added item every time I need to add to the heap?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A heap can be constructed in linear time, while the approach you propose will require O(N log(N)) time. Better construct heap in a separate function for better performance.

Comment: Even when I don't have an array to start with? I was planning on to just add item to Heap when I need to. Thanks!

Comment: @Dino55 - if you add elements one by one you of course have no better option than adding them one by one. Your question was "Why is there a construct heap method.". The answer is because constructing a heap from an array can be done in better complexity than adding the elements of the array one by one.

Comment: Even if you add elements one by one, you only need to call `percolateDown` each time if you need the heap invariant to be true in between adding elements. build/construct is for situations where your array doesn't need to be a heap until *after* it has several elements. If that's not your situation then fair enough.

Comment: @SteveJessop I am not sure I understand your comment. What I say is that if you add elements one by one you have to call percolateDown for each element and the solution proposed by OP is as good as you can get. However if you have a whole array construction can be more efficient. So constructHeap is usually for the second case.

Comment: @Dino55 If you don't have the array *yet* but you know that you are going to add *N* elements to the (now empty) heap, just temporarily add them to an array and initialize the heap with the special method `buildHeap` accepting an array. You can however keep things simple and just add them one after another to the heap unless you find out that some performance improvement is needed.

Comment: Thank you all very much :) I went with @leemes suggestion and created an array first. Then use PercolateUP() whenever I need to insert!