# Is it possible to build a Min Heap only using percolate down?

Tags: heap

Is it possible to build a Min Heap only using percolate down ( not using percolate up ) ?

Comment: Yes, but it is significanly more complex than percolate up.  So why would you want to?

Comment: @ChrisDodd because prof wants us to do so... but I found out that using comparator could help me easily implement min heap with percolate down. Thank you btw

Comment: A yes/no question is not very useful. You could make your question more interesting by providing your attempt (code), and where it goes wrong -- providing the input, the output you get, and what was expected instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I implement a heap using only percolateDown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12668624/can-i-implement-a-heap-using-only-percolatedown)

Answer (score 0):

We cannot build a heap using perlocate up method because lets say if we are processing ith element and as part of perlocate up process, we swap the position of ith element with its parent. Now the parent might not satisfy heap property because it can be greater than both children of ith element and thus it will violate the heap property.